# Постановка запятой перед союзом

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, в следующем предложении можно ли поставить запятую: Кем бы она ни была, женщина оказалась вовсе не сумасшедшей(,) и если пугала кого-то, то исключительно ради веселья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Женщина, кем бы она ни была, оказалась вовсе не сумасшедшей и если пугала кого-то, то (пугала) исключительно ради веселья.***

1) **Запятая не ставится,** так как соединяет однородные сказуемые по схеме (1 + 2).

**Предикативная основа**: женщина (1) оказалась вовсе не сумасшедшей и если (2) пугала, то  (3) пугала.

Союз ЕСЛИ...ТО является **градационным** (другие союзы КАК...ТАК И, НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И и др.).

2) В начале предложения должно быть существительное ***женщина***, а не местоимение ***она***.