# «Даже если бы...» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение, частицы

Нужна ли запятая перед «даже»?
*Она бы слукавила, **даже** если бы сказала, что у неё самой нет этой неприязни.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Она бы слукавила, даже если бы сказала, что у неё самой нет этой неприязни.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором придаточная часть соединена с главной с помощью усилительной частицы **даже** и союза **если**.
Без частицы, которая употреблена для смыслового выделения, запятая перед «если» ставится по общим правилам: *Она бы слукавила, **если** бы сказала...*

У Розенталя ([§ 34. Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах, п. 6](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=71)):
Не расчленяются <...> простые союзы и примыкающая к ним усилительная частица (***даже если***, лишь когда, лишь только, только лишь, едва лишь, едва только, чуть только и т. п.).

*Но победу,

гений,

можешь праздновать,

**даже если** ты совсем один,

если у тебя,

светильник разума,

гривенника нет на керосин.*
Е. Евтушенко

*Но в любом случае, **даже если** бы она не любила Вильчура, замуж за Юрковского она бы не пошла* (Т. Доленга-Мостович).

[**ДАЖЕ**, *частица* и *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_148)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна.

**Частица «даже» может стоять перед союзом в сложноподчиненном предложении. В этом случае запятая перед «даже» ставится, а между «даже» и союзом отсутствует.**

Примечание: запятая перед "если" или перед сочетаниями с "если" (напр. *даже если*) может не ставится только в связке с союзом "и" (*и если*).

Пример: [Постановка запятой перед союзом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454548/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC)